# MySQL for Test Website

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache

I am making a website similar to Moodle. It basically holds tests for students. The confusion comes in when allowing multiple types of questions on the tests and how to create the tables to store the data.

The **test_info** table will contain the test ID and description.
The **test** table will contain Test ID and Question ID pairs.
To get the questions for a test this will require a "SELECT * FROM test WHERE testID=$tID" which will take a substantial amount of time to execute when the database gets large.

Originally the **questions** table contained the question, 4 possibilities and the answer.

How should I store the data for multiple questions and multiple types of questions in a database?

For Example:

Test 51 - "Intro Mathmatics"

Question 1: What is 2+2?
A: 4 B: 12
C: 7 D: 8

Question 2: (0,103) is the range for the equation y=2x/(100x)?
True False

*This results in data with 2 different sizes*

Questions:

| Question | A | B | C | D | Correct |

| Question | Correct   |

If I store these in 1 table it will waste 4 50Char Var-Chars per question and if I store these in 2 separate tables, how will the SELECT know which table to select from?

**Questions**:
| TestID | TableID | QuestionID |

**Questions1:**
| Ques | A | B | C | D | Correct |

**Questions2:**
| Ques | A | B | C | D | Correct |

What a nightmare.

Comment: Selecting from a table based on a unique ID will take a "substantial amount of time"?  Are we measuring in picoseconds?

Comment: How are you inserting the answer options in your table

Answer (score 0):

Put the answer in their own table:

```
answers (answer_id, question_id, description, sequence)
```

and put the correct answer_id in the question table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you data structure will be like this:

```
Table1 :Test

id:
TestName:

Table2: Questions:

id:
test_id:
Question:
Answer: //say a,b,c,d

Table3:Answers

id:
question_id:
Anwser Option: //say a,b,c,d
Answer:
```

Sql For tables with data:
The data will help you in understanding the structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tests` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Test` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test2`
--

INSERT INTO `test2` (`id`, `Test`) VALUES
(1, 'Test1');


//////////////////////////////////////

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Question` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Answer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `questions`
--

INSERT INTO `questions` (`id`, `test_id`, `Question`, `Answer`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'question1', 'a'),
(2, 2, 'Question2', 'd');

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answer_option` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Answer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `answers`
--

INSERT INTO `answers` (`id`, `question_id`, `answer_option`, `Answer`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'a', 'True'),
(2, 1, 'b', 'False'),
(3, 2, 'a', 'Asnwer1'),
(4, 2, 'b', 'Answer2'),
(5, 2, 'c', 'Answer3'),
(6, 2, 'd', 'Answer4'),
(7, 2, 'e', 'Answer5');
```

Comment: Is there an advantage of storing the answers in a separate table instead of inline with the Questions?
I want this to be able to handle a LARGE amount of data University size.
ex: | Ques | A | B | C | D | Answer|

can you give an example record for the Questions and Answers table?
Thanks

Comment: Yes , here you can put all types of questions (questions with 1 answer or 2 answer or 3 answer or 4 answer or even more than that).In inline table you will be bound for max upto 4 answers. and i think this is better way....

Answer (score 0):

An empty `VARCHAR(50)` only needs six bits, which means that it will (most likely) take up one byte only on the disk. The `VAR` in `VARCHAR` means that the space usage will adapt to the actual data. This means that using one table will "waste" only four bytes per question.

Since you have two types of questions that you handle in two different ways in the code, your two-table approach is viable as well.

The recommended approach is:

Note that four-answer questions and yes-no questions are both special cases of a multiple-choice question. Store these in the database. One possible schema:

```
question: question_id (PK), test_id (FK), text
answer: answer_id (PK), question_id (FK), text, is_correct
```

PK = primary key, FK = foreign key